# Unable to make Dbeaver connection in a new windows session

Tags: dbeaver

I need help in below scenario.

We have two DBS, DB1 and DB2

when  windows user (user1) user try to login to DB1 via windows it opens successfully, keeping this session open I make another windows session with the same user (user1) and login on DB2, the DB2 opens in the first windows that was created with DB1 instead of opening in a new windows session.

So user1 is unable to have two different windows sessions for each DB(DB1  and DB2).

I have tried to make this session through windows command line using below parameters but we are getting the same behavior as explained above.

-con "driver=DB2 LUW|host="device_ip"|port=50005|database="DBName"|user="username"|password="password"|openConsole=true|connect=true|create=false|showSystemObjects=true"

-reuseWorkspace "driver=DB2 LUW|host="device_ip"|port=50005|database="DBName"|user="username"|password="password"|openConsole=true|connect=true|create=false|showSystemObjects=true"

-newInstance "driver=DB2 LUW|host="device_ip"|port=50005|database="DBName"|user="username"|password="password"|openConsole=true|connect=true|create=false|showSystemObjects=true"

please guide how we can make a DB connection in a new windows session.